# Mysql count with where clause - correct syntax

Tags: mysql

I need help with getting the correct syntax for a query, I need to exclude ids from the views count that are my own id.

Something like the below but obvs first where clause is wrong and just illustrates what I want to achieve.

```
SELECT    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*, 
          Count(DISTINCT l.lead_id) AS leads, 
          Count(DISTINCT v.user_id) AS views where user_id != %s // This wont work
FROM      trading t 
LEFT JOIN leads l ON t.trade_id = l.trade_id 
LEFT JOIN post_view v ON t.trade_id = v.trade_id 
WHERE     t.user_id = %s AND t.published = %s 
GROUP BY  t.trade_id 
ORDER BY  timestamp DESC 
LIMIT     $start, $perpage
```

Update:

Tried using a sub query

```
SELECT    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*, 
          Count(DISTINCT l.lead_id) AS leads 
FROM      trading t 
LEFT JOIN leads l 
ON        t.trade_id = l.trade_id 
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT Count(DISTINCT user_id) AS views
FROM post_view WHERE user_id != %s ) as v
ON        t.trade_id = v.trade_id 
WHERE     t.user_id = %s 
AND       t.published = %s 
GROUP BY  t.trade_id 
ORDER BY  timestamp DESC 
LIMIT     $start, $perpage
```

I am now getting this error: Unknown column 'v.trade_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: There is no SQL Syntax select ..as .. where

Comment: yer I know - that's what I want to achieve with the right syntax

Comment: What should be the logic behind this?

Comment: I want to count user ids but not include my own id in the count

Comment: The query works without the first where clause but includes my own id

Comment: WHERE     t.user_id = %s and t.user_id !=  <my_own_userid>
AND       t.published = %s ?

Comment: I need all row results from trading - changing the regular where clause will return no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an additional condition to the second left join: "AND v.user_id != %s". You can also avoid the use of the parameter with "AND v.user_id != t.user_id"

```
SELECT    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*, 
          Count(DISTINCT l.lead_id) AS leads, 
          Count(DISTINCT v.user_id) AS views
FROM      trading t 
LEFT JOIN leads l ON t.trade_id = l.trade_id 
LEFT JOIN post_view v ON t.trade_id = v.trade_id AND v.user_id != %s
WHERE     t.user_id = %s AND t.published = %s 
GROUP BY  t.trade_id 
ORDER BY  timestamp DESC 
LIMIT     $start, $perpage
```

An other way to do that, preserving the post_view data, is using the IF statement that works at row level

```
SELECT    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*, 
          Count(DISTINCT l.lead_id) AS leads, 
          Count(DISTINCT IF(v.user_id=%s,NULL,v.user_id)) AS views
FROM      trading t 
LEFT JOIN leads l ON t.trade_id = l.trade_id 
LEFT JOIN post_view v ON t.trade_id = v.trade_id
WHERE     t.user_id = %s AND t.published = %s 
GROUP BY  t.trade_id 
ORDER BY  timestamp DESC 
LIMIT     $start, $perpage
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly difficult due to the fact that I don't know your particular table columns and how they are related. It looks like you are trying to COUNT data from two tables that are related in some way.

The simplest way to do this is to use a derived table (subselect).

```
SELECT    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*, 
          Count(DISTINCT l.lead_id) AS leads, 
          Count(DISTINCT v.user_id) AS views where user_id != %s // This wont work
FROM      trading t 
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT subL.trade_id, Count(DISTINCT subL.lead_id)
  FROM leads ) l
ON        t.trade_id = l.trade_id 
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT subV.t Count(DISTINCT subV.user_id)
  FROM post_view subV
  WHERE subV.user_id != %s ) v
ON        t.trade_id = v.trade_id 
WHERE     t.user_id = %s 
AND       t.published = %s 
GROUP BY  t.trade_id 
ORDER BY  timestamp DESC 
LIMIT     $start, $perpage
```

I haven't tested this. But this will probably get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching count based on lead_id & user_id . I think best is to split them into 2 separate queries. Reason is because you require your `WHERE` condition to be present only for the 'user_id' count & not for 'lead_id'. You can remove the line from the above query:

`Count(DISTINCT v.user_id) AS views where user_id != %s // This wont work`

And create a new query as:

```
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*, 
Count(DISTINCT v.user_id) AS userviews 
FROM      trading t 
LEFT JOIN post_view v ON t.trade_id = v.trade_id 
WHERE     t.user_id = %s AND v.user_id != %s AND t.published = %s 
GROUP BY  t.trade_id 
ORDER BY  timestamp DESC 
LIMIT     $start, $perpage`
```

Please also note that you should ideally not use mysql keywords like `views`. Hence I have changed that to `userviews`.

Answer (score -1):

I have changed in your sql query syntax but one confusion is that you are using group by t.trade_id but not use any field of trading table in aggregate function.

```
SELECT    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS t.*, 
          Count(DISTINCT l.lead_id) AS leads, 
          Count(DISTINCT v.user_id) AS views  
FROM      trading t 
LEFT JOIN leads l 
ON        t.trade_id = l.trade_id 
LEFT JOIN post_view v 
ON        t.trade_id = v.trade_id 
WHERE     t.user_id LIKE '%s' 
AND       t.published LIKE '%s' AND v.user_id NOT LIKE '%s'
GROUP BY  t.trade_id 
ORDER BY  timestamp DESC 
LIMIT     $start, $perpage
```

Comment: this will return no results - I only want to change the views count to not include my id